# Writing fully manageable administrative template

Tags: group-policy

I'm writing administrative template for GPO. For example my policy is like this:

```
CLASS MACHINE
    CATEGORY !!GMC
        CATEGORY !!Programos
            CATEGORY !!VNC
                POLICY !!VNChttpCon
                    KEYNAME SOFTWARE\TightVNC\Server
                    EXPLAIN !!VNChttpConExpl
                    VALUENAME "AcceptHttpConnections"
                        VALUEON 1
                        VALUEOFF 0
                 END POLICY
             END CATEGORY
         END CATEGORY
     END CATEGORY
```

How I should change this coude to be fully manageable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little sparse, but a look at the 'KEYNAME' makes me think you're referring to this issue:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739211(v=ws.10).aspx

As described in the article, a policy is only considered "Fully managed" if the registry key is one of these locations:

```
 - HKLM\Software\Policies (preferred location)
 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
 - HKCU\Software\Policies (preferred location)
 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
```

In your case, the correct answer is that the software needs to add its configuration items to these sub-locations. It's unlikely you can do that, so unfortunately you're stuck. Your ADM is still perfectly usable, but you need to be very careful about tattooing.

---

As @jscott kindly points out below - a great alternative to custom ADM's is to use Group Policy Preference Registry settings. Ticking the "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" solves the tattooing issue. They're not so portable or distributable, but they're highly transparent and easy to use.

Plus, if you copy a GPP (Or a group of them, whatever) using the GUI, you can past the results to a text file. It's all XML, and you can simply paste them again in future by copying the text and pasting in the GUI.

Comment: Great explaination. In cases such as OPs, we've moved from creating unmanaged ADMs to using GPP registry items with the "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" setting.

Comment: @jscott Good point about GPP's - I can't believe I forgot about them!